# batch file to convert .mp4 to .mp3 crashes half the times

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file, vlc

I am using a batch file to access my portable VLC executable to convert an mp4 to an mp3:

```
set arg1=%1   REM -> arg1={my_mp4_full_path}
set arg2=%2   REM -> arg2={my_mp3_full_path}
echo %arg1%
echo %arg2%
REM batch file is in the same directory as "VLCPlayer" folder
"%~dp0\VLCPlayer\VLCPortable.exe" -I dummy %arg1% --sout=#transcode{acodec=mp3,ab=128,vcodec=dummy}:std{access="file",mux="raw",dst=%arg2%} vlc://quit
```

When I run this script the first time, vlc crashes and I get an unplayable mp3 file, however when I run the script again the script works and I get a playable mp3. Is there a way to remedy this, or make it consistent? I don't see why running it twice would yield different outcomes.

No I don't have `ffmpeg` on my computer it is unrecognizable internal or external command.

Note that I face the same problem when using powershell to perform the same task, when I import my function from a .psm1 script:

```
function ConvertToMp3(
    [switch] $inputObject,
    [string] $vlc = '{PAth_TO_PORTABLE_VLC}\VLCPortable.exe')
{
    PROCESS {
        $codec = 'mp3';
        $oldFile = $_;
        $newFile = $oldFile.FullName.Replace($oldFile.Extension, ".$codec").Replace("'","");
        &"$vlc" -I dummy "$oldFile" ":sout=#transcode{acodec=$codec,
        vcodec=dummy}:standard{access=file,mux=raw,dst=`'$newFile`'}" vlc://quit | out-null;

        # delete the original file
        Remove-Item $oldFile;
        }
}
```

I get the same random output that sometimes works, sometimes crashes.

**Update:**
I feel like I should add more info of how I use the batch file:
I have a python script `Convert.py` and I call my batch file inside using `os.system()`:

```
mp4_to_convert = arguments.file
full_path_mp4 = os.path.join(outdir,mp4_to_convert)
mp3_to_convert_to = mp4_to_convert.replace(".mp4",".mp3")
full_path_mp3 = os.path.join(outdir,mp3_to_convert_to)
command_string = """Convert_Script.bat \"{}\" \"{}\"""".format(full_path_mp4, full_path_mp3)
os.system(command_string)
```

This is the documentation of `os.system()`:

> **os.system(command)**
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This
> is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has
> the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in
> the environment of the executed command. If command generates any
> output, it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream.
>
> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
> the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
> meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
> value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
> after running command. The shell is given by the Windows environment
> variable COMSPEC: it is usually cmd.exe, which returns the exit status
> of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell, consult your
> shell documentation.

Any pointers or suggestions would be helpful, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: No need to assigne the batch file arguments to variables, just use `%1`, `%2` immediately; however, try using them with proper quotation, like `"%~1"` and `"%~2"` to avoid trouble with spaces or other special characters...

Comment: the behaviour you describe very much sounds like a typical [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) - which would mean, you don't show us all your (relevant) code.

Comment: @aschipfl the arguments provided are already string with surrounding quotations so when I call a path with white spaces it would work.

Comment: @Stephan it seems adding `call` before the last line in my batch file bumps the success rate to 90% or so. Thank you.

Comment: @Mofi you are right I removed the additional backslash.